# Is the stone an item from the comics?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield, inhumans

In the *Agents of SHIELD* episode *Scars* (S02E20),

> Raina

has a vision of a stone that keeps changing from liquid to solid and back again.

Jiaying explains

> there are legends of this stone being a Kree weapon intended to kill all of the Inhumans.

Is this stone an existing item or concept from the comics?

Comment: I have two theories - either it's the alien symbiote, thus gearing up for Spider-Man in the MCU... or it's the stone that the Diviners came from. Notice the Diviners are a square shaft of metal that's twisted along the vertical axis, and the stone in its solid form has numerous square-shaped holes in it. Just a theory, though.

Comment: Or it might be the Moonstone that is supposedly part of a Kree device.

Answer (score 9):

**No, the stone we see in S2E20 "Scars" does not appear to be anything from the comics.**

> --- **WARNING: UN-MARKED SPOILERS THROUGHOUT** ---

The alien [**"stone"**](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Kree_Stone), seen briefly mid-way through the episode, is a complete mystery at the moment. Most of what we know comes from a single brief glance of the artifact and dialogue in the same episode. Here is what we know about it:

*While describing her latest vision, Raina alarms Gordon with her description:*

> **RAINA:** Last night i saw something beautifully peculiar... it's hard to
>   describe. It was a giant stone, but not a stone. And then, suddenly,
>   it was... like an ocean, waves crashing against the shore.
>
> **GORDON:** Hold on. This stone... were there deep cavities carved into
>   it?
>
> **RAINA:** How did you know?

*She is next seen discussing the artifact with Jiaying and Gordon:*

> **JIAYING:** This could mean the end of us.
>
> **RAINA:** I don't understand. Have you come across this before?
>
> **JIAYING:** Only through stories passed down by our ancestors. It's Kree,
>   dangerous... intended to destroy our people.
>
> **RAINA:** But didn't they make us?
>
> **JIAYING:** ... then they decided that we were a mistake. Gordon, do you
>   think you could locate it? Confirm that it exists?
>
> **GORDON:** If it's Kree, I suppose I could find a connection to tether.

*Later, we get a glimpse of the artifact itself:*

[image]

*Afterwards, the SHIELD personnel discuss the artifact (and why the Inhumans would be after it):*

> **GONZALEZ:** We should have destroyed it when we had the chance.
>
> **BOBBI:** You know we couldn't risk it.
>
> **WEAVER:** There were too many variables.
>
> **MAY:** So this is alien.
>
> **GONZALEZ:** Recovered from a dig site nearly a hundred years ago.
>
> **WEAVER:** Its energy signatures are unlike anything we've seen before.

This now represents the sum of what we know about the "stone" as fact. That being said, there are a couple of theories that make sense given the direction of the MCU and AoS so far:

---

### The Less Likely Theory

[image]

The first theory, but also the less likely of the two, is that the stone is an alien symbiote creature known as a [Klyntar](http://marvel.wikia.com/Klyntar). The symbiote is most famously associated with [Spider-Man](http://marvel.wikia.com/Spider-Man_(Peter_Parker)), as his black costume, which was actually an alien symbiote he encountered during the original [Secret Wars](http://marvel.wikia.com/Marvel_Super_Heroes:_Secret_Wars) event.

**Supporting Evidence:**

- Spider-Man is being introduced into the MCU in Captain America: Civil War.
- Several people "in the know", including [Kevin Feige](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Feige) himself, have speculated that Spidey *might* get his black suit in Infinity War 1 or 2.
- The "stone" is unlike anything SHIELD has seen before, yet they have encountered Kree technology & biology before. The stone may have been brought to Earth by the Kree but is not *actually* Kree in origin.
- The "stone" appeared to be changing shape on its own, perhaps even by will.
- In its liquid/transforming state, the "stone" appears nearly identical to the symbiote creatures (a black oily substance).
- The symbiotes are violent, near-unstoppable creatures whose only weakness is sound. They could, in theory, make a formidable weapon against Inhumans.

---

### The More Likely Theory

[image]

The second, and more likely theory, is that the "stone" is actually the source of the [Diviners](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Diviner) seen already throughout Season 2 of AoS.

**Supporting Evidence:**

- The artifact is said to be Kree in origin.
- The "stone" in its solid form appears to be made of the same material as the Diviners.
- The liquefying effect of the stone is very similar to the effect it has on humans who touch the Diviners, turning them into some sort of black, stony ash-like material.
- The "stone" contains several square-shaped holes, and the Diviners look like a square peg that was then twisted vertically.
- When held by a latent Inhuman, a Diviner's surface "morphs" to show Kree writing. The effect is very similar to the liquid-like transformation of the "stone" when we see it.
- If the "stone" is indeed the source of the Diviners, it could conceivably be a weapon against the [Inhumans](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Inhumans) by un-doing the [terrigenesis](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Terrigenesis) performed by the Diviners. This would essentially render all Inhumans human again, thereby "destroying" them as a people.

---

As it stands, we will simply have to wait for future episodes and hope that more information about the "stone" is revealed. However, given that it appears to be central to the upcoming conflict between SHIELD and the Inhumans, it's fairly certain that haven't seen the last of this artifact.

**UPDATE:** At the end of the season finale "S.O.S.", Simmons is working near the stone and finds the door unlatched. As she goes to re-seal it,

> the stone seemingly comes alive and leaps out of the case, absorbing a screaming Simmons into it before returning to normal.

This scene would seem to lend heavy evidence towards the first theory, with the stone being a living entity of some kind.

**UPDATE 2:** As of Season 3, we now know that the stone is a Kree device that can open portals to other worlds when certain vibrational frequencies are directed at it. An ancient faction of Hydra has been in possession of the stone for centuries while attempting to release [an Inhuman](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hive_(Earth-616)) trapped on a desolate world.

Comment: Now that the stone has eaten Simmons it is less probable that the stone is made of diviner metal as that would be lethal for the character. Maybe it really is a symbiote.

Comment: It could also be the Moonstone (part of a Kree artifact) that is absorbed by a scientist that becomes the character called Moonstone http://marvel.wikia.com/Karla_Sofen_(Earth-616)

Comment: Unless Simmons has Kree DNA? Wouldn't that be an interesting twist after seeing her reaction this season to "enhanced" people?

Comment: With Moonstone being a villain and a hero at times, it would be interesting to see Simmons as Moonstone. Her character has shown signs of villainy throughout this season and she seems to wish she had the power to stop what she perceives as evil. If she were to gain these powers it could throw her over the edge of the hero/villain line.

Comment: @MarekAndreansky Agent Simmons is going to be the new Spiderman? :-P

Comment: @TylerH Nah, it's probably the Moonstone or some other Kree shenanigan :D

Answer (score 1):

While not a match of the stones physical description, when I heard "Kree weapon" my first thought were the [Kree Sentries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentry_(Kree)). There have been a number of them over the years but the most notable one is [Sentry-459](http://marvel.wikia.com/Sentry_459_(Earth-616)).

It was part of a Kree scientific expedition to experiment on humans, which ultimately resulted in the Inhumans. It stayed behind on Earth to watch the Inhumans progress and notify the Kree of this, including specifically when they discovered and used Terrigan Crystals. It was usually controlled by Ronan the Accuser and defeated by Mar-Vell. It's strength and laser beams don't make it a specific threat to Inhumans but it has also been equipped with a [Nega-bomb](http://marvel.com/universe/Nega-Bomb) in some versions, which has been used in recent years against Inhumans.

It's physical description is that of a typical robot which certainly doesn't fit with the shape-shifting stone in the show but it could just be the MCU version of one of these Sentries.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it is a transport device. I derive this from the fact that the Kree use stone in some of their devices. However, it could also be tied into the skrulls. Since Kree and Skrull have been tied so closely together as enemies. Seeing the kree from the TAHITI project usually implies Skrulls are bound to be around. However, there is, (what I hope to be) the introduction of the brood. I can;t find any images to reference to but the brood travel by a means that dissolves when landing. They said they found it in a dig site 100 years ago. Also in the Age of Ultron series the brood do make an appearance.

Comment: But is it something from the comics?